# reconstructing a simple polytope from its graph

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polytopes

I'm reading Kalai's paper on the reconstruction of simple polytopes from their graphs and there is something I don't understand.

we define a good acyclic orientation as an acyclic orientation for which every non empty face $F$ of $P$, $G(F)$ has exactly one sink. Take $O$ such an orientation.

define $h_k^O$ as the number of vertices of index $k$ in $G(P)$ and define $$f^O = h_0^O + 2h_1^O + \dots + 2^dh^O_d$$

Then it states that $f^O\geqslant f$ ($f$ the number of faces) and $O$ is good iff $f^0 = f$. I don't get these two implications. It should be easy but I don't see it.

PS: a link to the paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316588900647

EDIT: Problem solved

Comment: It might help to give a link to the paper, or at least its bibliographic data.

Comment: I'm glad you have solved the problem. Let me encourage you to write up your solution and post it as an answer, to help those who come after you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on the following link

https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/telling-a-simple-polytope-from-its-graph/